# How to save month-wise mails and aslo divide mails based on time using gmail api and save the output to csv or convert it into df?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gmail, gmail-api

This code below gets us the messages count for every 30 days from the time period of message sent.

**This code gets us:(In-detail)**

1.Amazon first mail to my mail with a particular phase(here first order).

2.Convert that epoch format into time date and using timedelta And getting count of mails sent in the interval of 30 days.

**The output for this code will be like this:**

```
Amazon first order:

1534476682000

Amazon total orders between 2018-08-01 and 2018-09-01: 20

Amazon total orders between 2018-09-01 and 2018-10-01: 11

Amazon total orders between 2018-10-01 and 2018-11-01: 15

Amazon total orders between 2018-11-01 and 2018-12-01: 7

Amazon total orders between 2018-12-01 and 2019-01-01: 19

Amazon total orders between 2019-01-01 and 2019-02-01: 23

Amazon total orders between 2019-02-01 and 2019-03-01: 12
```

**Code:**

```
#amazonfirstorder
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='from:auto-confirm@amazon.in subject:(your amazon.in order of )',labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()

messages = results.get('messages', [])


print('\nFilpkart first order:')
if not messages:
    print (" ")
else:
    print (" ")

    msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[-1]['id']).execute()
    #print(msg['snippet'])
    a=(msg['internalDate'])
    ts = int(a)
    ts /= 1000
    year=int(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y'))
    month=int(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%m'))
    #print(year)
    #print(month)
    print(msg['internalDate'])

    log_results = []
    start_date = datetime(year,month,1)
#start_date = datetime(2016,1,1)
    end_date = datetime.today()
    increment = relativedelta(months=1)
    target_date = start_date + increment

    while target_date <= end_date:

        timestamp_after = int(start_date.timestamp())  # timestamp of start day
        timestamp_before = int(target_date.timestamp())  # timestamp of start day + 30 days

        query = f'from:(auto-confirm@amazon.in) subject:(your amazon.in order of ) after:{timestamp_after} before:{timestamp_before}'
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()

        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        orders = len(messages)
        start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        target_date_str = target_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print(f"\nFlipkart total orders between {start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} and {target_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}: {orders}")

        log_results.append(dict(start=start_date_str, end=target_date_str, orders=orders))

    # update interval
        start_date += increment
        target_date += increment

    return log_results



if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_results = main()
```

Now i have two problems :

**First**

How to save the output of that code into csv file.

**Second**:

The above code gets us 30 days mails count,What i need is i need the count of mails i received before 12.00 PM in month-wise and after 12 PM in month-wise and save them in csv.

**OUTPUT i need for 2nd Problem** :

```
Amazon total orders between 2018-09-01 and 2018-10-01 before 12:00 PM : 11

Amazon total orders between 2018-10-01 and 2018-11-01 before 12:00 PM : 15

Amazon total orders between 2018-11-01 and 2018-12-01 before 12:00 PM : 7

Amazon total orders between 2018-12-01 and 2019-01-01 before 12:00 PM : 19

Amazon total orders between 2018-09-01 and 2018-10-01 after 12:00 PM : 3

Amazon total orders between 2018-10-01 and 2018-11-01 after 12:00 PM : 6

Amazon total orders between 2018-11-01 and 2018-12-01 after 12:00 PM : 88

Amazon total orders between 2018-12-01 and 2019-01-01 after 12:00 PM : 26
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code please?

Comment: "automate it in a regular interval of 30 days" you’re looking for a task scheduler am I right? Take a look into the [Advanced Python Scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) otherwise I’m reading question wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what already proposed, but in this case you would calculate the increment as exactly one month instead of 30 days (see the use of `relativedelta` instead of `timedelta`):

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    log_results = []

    start_date = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    end_date = datetime.today()
    increment = relativedelta(months=1)
    target_date = start_date + increment

    while target_date <= end_date:

        timestamp_after = int(start_date.timestamp())  # timestamp of start day
        timestamp_before = int(target_date.timestamp())  # timestamp of start day + 30 days

        query = f'from:(auto-confirm@amazon.in) subject:(your amazon.in order of ) after:{timestamp_after} before:{timestamp_before}'
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, labelIds=['INBOX']).execute()

        messages = results.get('messages', [])
        orders = len(messages)
        start_date_str = start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        target_date_str = target_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        print(f"\nAmazon total orders between {start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} and {target_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}: {orders}")

        log_results.append(dict(start=start_date_str, end=target_date_str, orders=orders))

        # update interval
        start_date += increment
        target_date += increment

    return log_results



if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_results = main()
    # Write to csv
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(log_results)
    df.to_csv('orders.csv')
```

Comment: Now it's working, I fixed the indentation of the return statement, which was exiting the loop after the first execution. 
If you want arbitrary intervals of time, just adjust the code by changing the dates. 
`
start_date = datetime(year=XXXX, month=X, day=X)
end_date = datetime(year=XXXX, month=X, day=X)
`
and remove the loop part and and increment.

Comment: Thanks for removing the bounty...
Anyways, check the documentation of 'datetime' module, the timestamp is alredy from 12 PM, so what you get is already what you ask.

Comment: couldnt figure out where to start the looping for after and before time and saving them to csv

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to loop through the dates with the interval you want.

The code below retrieves the messages of a user from a particular period of time, such as the month messages count.

You will need help to automate it to retrieve messages count for every 30 days.

For example, this code gets the messages from Jan 1, 2016 to Jan 30, 2016.

So from Jan 1, 2016 to Jan 1, 2019 you will need to automate it in a regular interval of 30 days.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import time
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'    
def main():
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get() 
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    end_date = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
    interval = relativedelta(months=1)
    current = datetime(2016, 1, 1)              # init to the start date 
    while current < end_date + interval:
         after = current.timestamp()
         before = (current + interval).timestamp()

         query = 'from:(auto-confirm@amazon.in) subject:(your amazon.in order of ) after:{} before:{}'.format(after, before)
         results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q=query, labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()

         messages = results.get('messages', [])
         print("\namazon total orders in {}: {}".format(current.strftime('%B %Y'), len(messages)))
         current += interval    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: For get the current date, you can use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, or `datetime.datetime.now()` if you want to use your current locale timezone. About the error, I will fix it, it should be `datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)`. Sorry for that.